# ConfirmPasswordController doesn't exist after upgrade from Laravel 5.8 to 6.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

I am working on a project which is in Laravel 5.8, and recently, I upgraded it to Laravel 6.0 with its packages dependencies versions too. The project was running fine. But, today, I update the composer via `composer update,` and it upgraded to Laravel 6.2. After that, I faced an error:

> App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController does not exist

Then I installed a fresh `Laravel-6.2` and generated basic scaffolding via `php artisan ui vue,` then, generated `login/registration` scaffolding via `php artisan ui vue --auth.` After that, I found `ConfirmPasswordController.`Then, I manually created `ConfirmPasswordController` in my running project and copied all of the codes from `ConfirmPasswordController` to my manually created `ConfirmPasswordController.` Then, the error has gone. Although I did not face any error related to this. But, I am confused about my approach. Is it right way what I did? Or it has a better way to solve this problem. I am confused about, If I face many issues for `php artisan ui vue --auth` in the next time. Would someone suggest me the right process, what should I do?

Comment: Try this command. Maybe this worked: composer dump-autoload

Comment: That controller was literally created yesterday, so its new and it lives in your application so composer doesn't touch any of that  .. there is also a middleware to go with that and a config key added

Comment: I did. I solved my problem for this error. But afraid about next. The process I described above is the right way to do this or any better solution? This was my question.

Comment: That controller comes with laravel/laravel by default, now. So no command needed for it to exist ... unfortunately there are no notes on the documentation about version updates inside 6.x so not sure where you will have to look for that type of information moving forward

Comment: @lagbox yes, I searched for the correct way for this. But, Not found! And I am afraid about my project, this is because my project is larger. Is there any problem for the previous authentication process with `php artisan ui vue --auth`? Althoug I did not face yet.

Comment: there is no issue with that, it is just unrelated to the auth controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel made the following additions and modifications from versions v6.0.0 to v6.2.0.

```
A app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php
M app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
M app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
M app/Http/Kernel.php
M config/auth.php
M resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

Please make sure these changes are in your Laravel instance though it sounds like they now are. You can see the diff of v6.0.0 to v6.2.0 [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/v6.0.0...v6.2.0#files_bucket). If you need to see v5.8.0 changes through 6.2.0, please go [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/v5.8.0...v6.2.0#files_bucket).

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading, you will need to copy it from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php

This is known, reference https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/36#issuecomment-539921924.